# Flattening a 2d list into 1d list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of 2D elements

```
m = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]]
```

and I want my output to be:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14 15
16 17 18
19 20
```

I tried this loop:

```
for i in range(3):
    for k in range(i,len(m),3):
        print(*m[i][k:k+3],sep='\t')
```

but it prints

```
1 2 3
4 5
6 7 8
9 10
11 12 13
14 15
16 17 18
```

and gives me an error

I'm not sure if it is possible since it is going on the next element. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: The second half of this question (dividing into groups of three for output) distinguishes it, but there's a lot of info about the flattening part in the answers over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet

```
m = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]]

flag=0

for i in range(len(m)):

    for j in range(len(m[i])):
        if(flag==3):
            print()
            flag=0
        print(m[i][j],end=" ")
        flag+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach like this would work:

```
m = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]]

curr = 0
for i in m:
  for j in i:
    curr += 1
    if(curr % 3 == 0):
      print(j)
    else:
      print(j, end = ' ')
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14 15
16 17 18
19 20
```

You can create a variable, `curr`, to act as a counter variable. Then, iterate through every element of `m`, and increment `curr` with each iteration. For every third element, given by `curr % 3 == 0%`, we print an element WITH a newline. For every not-third element, we print the element without a newline.

I hope this helped! Please let me know if you have any further questions or clarifications :)

Comment: Instead of creating ```curr```,  you can do ```for idx, j in enumerate(i)```, and ```idx``` acts the same as ```curr```.

Comment: thats a good point! imo i think declaring `curr` separately makes the code a bit easier to follow, but yes, your method would be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
x = list(itertools.chain(*m))
print([x[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(x),3)])
```

Of course, the above will print the whole thing as a list of lists, but you can go from there to printing each of the individual sublists.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like

```
count = 0
for arr in matrix:
    for num in arr:
        print(num, end=' ')
        count += 1
        if count == 3:
            print()
            count = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

#### one-line version:

```
print("".join([str(e)+" " if e%3!=0 else str(e)+"\n" for row in m for e in row]))
```

---

P.S. `m = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]]` as that of OP.

---

#### easy-to-read version:

`m` does not need to be identical to that of OP. Could be any 2d matrix.

```
flat = [e for row in m for e in row]
for i in range(len(flat)):
    if i%3 != 2 : print(flat[i], end = " ")
    else : print(flat[i], end = "\n")
if len(flat)%3 != 0: print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) combines all the sublists, and [`more_itertools.chunked`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) breaks that up into equal-sized segments.

```
from itertools import chain
from more_itertools import chunked

m = [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15], [16,17,18,19,20]]

for triplet in chunked(chain(*m), 3):
    print(*triplet)
```

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14 15
16 17 18
19 20
```

(The asterisks are for [unpacking](https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/#Asterisks_for_unpacking_into_function_call); in this case `print(*triplet)` is effectively the same as `print(triplet[0], triplet[1], triplet[2])`, and `print` automatically inserts a space between multiple arguments by default.)

P.S. Nine times out of ten, if you're mucking about with indexes in a Python loop, [you don't need to](https://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/).

Answer (score 0):

It has multiple ways to do that but easiest way is  one line approaching using list comprrehension.
`flat = [element for sublist in m for element in sublist]`

```
m = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]]
flat = [element for sublist in m for element in sublist]
print("Original list", m)
print("Flattened list", flat)
```

Comment: I believe this is the shortest and most efficient solution in native python. ```itertools``` would obviously be faster, but for someone who doesn't want to dabble into too many modules, this is great!

Comment: You still need to spit it up into threes, though. If this question were *only* about flattening, it would be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists).